# "Near jump or call to different CS" error in TASM

Tags: assembly, binary-search, dos, tasm, x86-16

I have been trying to understand a binary search algorithm using assembly, but have been getting an error `Near jump or call to different CS` whenever I try to assemble the code. The error is at the lines where I have used a JMP or one of its variant instructions. I'm using TASM, and my code is:

```
 DATA SEGMENT
 ARR DW 0000H,1111H,2222H,3333H,4444H,5555H,6666H,7777H,8888H,9999H
 LEN DW ($-ARR)/2
 KEY EQU 7777H
 MSG1 DB "KEY IS FOUND AT "
 RES DB "  POSITION",13,10," $"
 MSG2 DB "KEY NOT FOUND!!!.$"
 DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT 
ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
START:
  MOV AX,DATA
  MOV DS,AX
  MOV BX,00
  MOV DX,LEN
  MOV CX,KEY
AGAIN: CMP BX,DX
   JA FAIL
   MOV AX,BX
   ADD AX,DX
   SHR AX,1
   MOV SI,AX
   ADD SI,SI
   CMP CX,ARR[SI]
   JAE BIG
   DEC AX
   MOV DX,AX
   JMP AGAIN
  BIG:JE SUCCESS
   INC AX
   MOV BX,AX
   JMP AGAIN
  SUCCESS: ADD AL,01
   ADD AL,'0'
   MOV RES,AL
   LEA DX,MSG1
   JMP DISP
  FAIL: LEA DX,MSG2
  DISP: MOV AH,09H
   INT 21H
   MOV AH,4CH
   INT 21H     
  CODE ENDS
  END START
```

Comment: Take the habit to comment your assembly lines. In 3 months you won't remember *what* the program does nor *how*.

Comment: This code would have worked with EMU8086 because its syntax is less picky, but the answer provided by @Seki should correct it for TASM (and MASM)

Answer (score 2):

In your `CODE SEGMENT`, you are missing a coma to separate the segment declarations with `ASSUME` (at line 10). Change it to:

```
ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE
```